# angular : how prevent internal file such as web.config view-able from internet browser?

Tags: javascript, azure

My web.config in azure app service (linux )is view able (downloadable) via internet browser.

How to prevent it?

Thanks
alfred

Answer (score 0):

Configure your web server in order to deny that resource.

That duty is in the web server. You surely can do that from whichever application server layer, but's not the most proper component where to do that.